# Lighttable Internal Browser and localhost proxy

Tags: lighttable

Ok so this may be a dumb question or possibly something that just isn't supported but haven't had much luck finding an answer.

I'm testing out Light Table for use as my day to front end editor and have been trying to get a page loading in the internal browser without success. I have a weblogic server running my app which I can access from Chrome and other browsers but when I try to point Light Table's browser at the same url I get the generic proxy can't connect to destination.

My first thought was that this I needed to configure Light Table to work with the company proxy but I am able to get to other sites from light table using the built in browser and I have the env variables http/https_proxy set. Has anyone seen this issue or know of a fix/workaround?

Ubuntu 14.04

Light Table 0.7.0

Chrome 36.0.1985.125

Comment: Could you please paste your OS, LT, and (default) browser versions?

Comment: edited my post to include versions

Answer (score 0):

It's weird but sounds "reasonable" that you don't really need any proxy to access `localhost`. I'd check using 127.0.0.1 in your url rather than localhost if you already didn't.

I recall a weird issue probably unrelated on Ubuntu that prevented the right name resolution. The resume is to check that `/etc/hosts` should contain just `127.0.0.1 localhost` rather than `your_machine_name 127.0.0.1`

[lein repl error:Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22114716/lein-repl-errorconnection-refused/22179985#22179985)